# Display loaded dependencies in leiningen REPL

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm running into problems because the library I have appears to conflict with the published documentation. I had a few problems with getting the right version of things installed before, and I'm wondering if this is the cause.

Is there any way to print out which jars were loaded in the repl so I can check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(System/getProperty "java.class.path")
```

Comment: this won't tell me which specific jars were loaded though, right?

Comment: Actually the jars are their own separate entries on the classpath as returned by `System/getProperty`, even if they're included on the classpath because of matching a wildcard (`*` in the classpath string).

Answer (score 16):

You can also use query lein for

- the classpath with `lein classpath`
- a dependency tree printout with `lein deps :tree`

Answer (score 6):

This might also help:

`lein deps :tree` - shows a tree of dependencies that get pulled in

`[library "version" :exclusions [some-other-lib "version"]]` - exclude the `some-other-lib` that gets pulled in by some library.

You can then manually pull in the right version of `some-other-lib` by defining your own dependency vector.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

- using java interrop: `(System/getProperty "java.class.path")`, `(println (seq (.getURLs (java.lang.ClassLoader/getSystemClassLoader))))`
- [clojure/java.classpath](https://github.com/clojure/java.classpath) contains useful functions: like `system-classpath`
- `lein`: `lein classpath` and `lein deps :tree`
- `boot`: `boot show -p`, as well as useful function in [boot environnement](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Boot-Environment). Maybe have a look at [martinklepsch/boot-deps](https://github.com/martinklepsch/boot-deps).

For `boot`, I also wrote [nha/boot-deps](https://github.com/nha/boot-deps) that helps managing dependency conflicts.